# Python selenium - Select children elements

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium to get the elements of a url. Within this I need the links but a particular div tag.
I select the div by class name, and then the links by xpath. However, it returns all the links, also those that are not in the div. What am I doing wrong?

```
browser.get(url)

elems = []
try:
    obj_div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("jss504")
    try:
        elems = obj_div.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

print(len(elems))
```

As a result, I get 41. However, if I do the same with the browser object, I also have that same amount. The 41 links are not of the `obj_div` object, are of the entire browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath can be [bidirectional](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xquery-2nd-edition/9781491915080/ch04.html), meaning that it will find elements forward and backward.

As your xPath it not only asking for the context after, it will be able to look forward and backward in the DOM.

From the document:
**Forward step**
This step selects descendants or nodes appearing after the context node (or the context node itself).

**Reverse step**
This step selects ancestors or nodes appearing before the context node (or the context node itself).

You can try to replace xpath by css_selector:

```
    elems = obj_div.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href]")
```

Not that this code will never raise a `NoSuchElementException` exception. It will return an empty list if it cannot find what you are looking for.

If your first class element is unique, you can also simplify your code with just one query:

```
obj_div = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".jss504 a[href]")
```

Comment: @JeffC Point taken and changed to "can be", Only case it won't be as far as I know would be if you used absolute path. Using nested would make them always bidirectional. Not sure about the downvote, but you may provide a better option if you have. To me, xPath should be avoided at all cost anyways.

Comment: You'll have to provide some documentation on what "bidirectional" means in this case. As far as I know and have ever heard, all locators start at the top of the DOM and move down. There are cases where you can search up through ancestors or down through descendants. See my answer for an explanation of what OP is seeing but I do recommend your solution over what OP requested.

Comment: OP is not starting at the start of the DOM hence my answer was not broad enough. I will add the link requested

Comment: Can you point me to the portion of the linked page where it talks about XPath being bidirectional? I searched for the word but it did not appear on the page.

Comment: @JeffC it is might not be explicitly said in the document but implicitly. I have copied the implicite portion in my answer. For the explicite, you can get the information from that link as well: http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2018/05/16/mastering-xpath-for-selenium-test-automation/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for elements that are under the starting element. In order to do this, you must use the self axis, `.`, e.g. `.//a[@href]`. That indicates to start at the current element and search under. Because you did not include it, XPath searches the entire page even though your code would seem to indicate (it's sort of confusing that it works this way until you understand why) that it should start at the `obj_div` element and search only descendants.

Additional notes:

Your nested `try` is not necessary because you are using `.find_elements_*`. It always returns a collection so you have to see if the collection is empty to know if an element was found.

Your full code with the edits would look like

```
browser.get(url)

elems = []
try:
    obj_div = browser.find_element_by_class_name("jss504")
    elems = obj_div.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass

print(len(elems))
```

Having said all this, I would suggest you use the CSS selector as Nic Laforge suggested. I just wanted to explain the answer to your question and provide some additional feedback in case it would be useful to you in the future or to others.